# on click of button insert some values in input text box in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Just a small help as i am new to ligtning. i want insert value 'sfdc' in inputtext box on the click of button.
Could anyone please guide me for this, Below is my code.
Component code-----------------

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="strone" type="string"/>
    <ui:inputText aura:id="idone" value="{!v.strone}"/><br/>
    <ui:button label="reset" press="{!c.reset}"/>
    </aura:component>

javascript code----------------

reset:function(component, event, helper) {
          component.set("idone","sfdc");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the value to your attribute and it will show up on the input text via binding.

eg:

```
component.set("v.strone","sfdc");
```

Also, keep in mind that lightning is case-sensitive. Change your attribute type from `string` to `String`:

```
<aura:attribute name="strone" type="String"/>
```

Alternatively, you can directly set the value on your input like this:

```
component.find("idone").set("v.value","sfdc");
```

Comment: yeah gr8..thats work gr8. thanks for the reply

Comment: its working f9 with type="string"

Comment: Good to know - I'm guessing salesforce has taken that into account.